# Check if tabControl1 is null?

Tags: c#

How can i check if tabcontrol1 is null(no pages-tabs inside)??

I want this code for setting up my tab control when is null to visible=false;
and when its not null to visible=true;

I'm using this code in selection changed but nothing is happened.

```
 private void TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TabControl==null)
        {
            TabControl.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControl.Visible = true;
        }
```

But nothing it doesnt work.

Comment: There is a difference between a tab control not having any tabs or being null. Also, if your tab control doesn't have any tabs the code you posted will never be called. It also won't be called if your tab control is null, but that's a different story. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry i didnt knew that. I want to run the code when tabcontrol doesnt have any tabs.I have a button in each tab which closes specific tab.

Comment: There is no event that tells you that no pages are left.  The user cannot remove pages, your code does.  So you don't need an event to tell you this.  Simply check TabControl.TabCount after you removed the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way which it works. But please check if it is the right way.

```
private void TabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TabControl.SelectedTab == TabControl.TabPages[""])//
        {
            TabControl.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            TabControl.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is to check the [TabPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages(v=vs.110).aspx) property or the [TabCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabcount(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `TabControl`:

```
this.tabControl.Visible = !this.tabControl.TabCount == 0;
```

This code will set the `Visible` property to `false` if there are no tab pages.